# python nested loops with contents from two different files

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to write a script to password spray user credentials. It take a password from pass_list file and then tries all the usernames from user_list. Then it will take the next password and try all the users with it. However, this loop doesn't work the way I want it.

```
user_list = open('user_list.txt')
pass_list = open('pass_list.txt')

for pass_word in pass_list:
    print(pass_word)

    for user_name in user_list:
        print(user_name)
```

The problem is it prints the usernames and passwords only once. It is supposed to print all usernames for a single password. Then for the second password it is supposed to iterate over the users again.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a relatively new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11082165) Can you be more specific about your problem than "doesn't work the way I want it"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files can only be read once. Use `itertools.product`:

```
with open('user_list.txt') as users:
    with open('pass_list.txt') as passwords:
        for username, password in itertools.product(users, passwords):
            print(username, password)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in your code.

1. It should be `pass_list=open('pass_list.txt','r')` #=== Open file to read.
2. It should be `print(pass_list.read())`  #=== Read the file

You can use `print(pass_list.readlines())` which will create a list and add all the lines in the file to the list.